# passing a value to float format specifier in java

Tags: java, c, floating-point

to round a number to n-decimal places, in C, I use the following method:-

```
#include <stdio.h>          
void main()    
{    
float a=0.12685;      
int n=3;     
printf("%.*f",n,a);    
}
```

NOTE:- only '*' can be used to pass a value to the float format specifier. statements like %.xf give error.

Is there a way to do the same thing in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: @Tunaki. I don't think this is a duplicate, because in this question the number of decimal places is variable, not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You could just *build* the format string:

```
double a = 0.12685;
int n = 3;
System.out.printf("%." + n + "f", a);
```

You can also use a `NumberFormat`:

```
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getInstance();
fmt.setMinimumFractionDigits(n);
fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(n);
System.out.print(fmt.format(a));
```

Both will print:

```
0.127
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your float value to round to 3 decimal places then you could work like:

```
float a = 0.12685f;
System.out.printf("%.3f", a);
//Output:
0.127
```

Better way would be to use formatter like:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
System.out.println(df.format(a));
//output
0.127
```

Comment: I want to take the number of decimal places from user as input.

Comment: i.e n is user input.     ` #include <stdio.h>          
void main()    
{    
a=0.12685;      
scanf("%d",&n);     
printf("%.*f",n,a);    
}`

Comment: This answer doesn't use a dynamic number of decimals as defined in variable `n`.